# JMSSerializer exclusion strategy and groups on deserialization

Tags: php, symfony, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

There are nice annotations in JMSSerializer `@MaxDeepth` and `@Groups`. Why do they dont work on deserialization, but work only for serialization? How do I enable them for deseriailzation too?

Sources of the jmmserializer show that exclusion strategies are not ignored, they just equal to null.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I've got solution, it was pretty easy =) actually I was confused by FOSRestBundle's `@View(serializerGroups={"a","b"}`, but actually they work for serialization and not deserialization. So solution is just to send regular context with correct options to the serializer:

```
$context = new DeserializationContext();
$context->setGroups(['a', 'b']);
$context->enableMaxDepthChecks(); // if you wish
$serializer->deserialize($content, $classname, 'json', $context);
```